# read html table content with specific class

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I have news page that shows my news. I used table to show headlines.

```
<table class="news">
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

I have other tables in this page. But I want to get this table in another page. I searched and just find this way:

```
$text = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/news");
echo strip_tags($text, "<table><tr><th><td>");
```

Output contains all tables in news page. My goal is just table with class "news".

How can I do that?

Comment: I suggest you to use PHP DOMparser.

Comment: @Kristiyan so could you explain how can I do that? then maybe you can show me a good reference. tnx.

Comment: can you show your html response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created sample code with two tables. You can see the output at the end

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOT
<table class="news" border='1'>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>New 1 - first </td><td>New 1 - second </td></tr>
<tr><td>New 1 - fifth </td><td>New 1 - forth</td></tr>

</table>
<table class="another_news" border='1'>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Another New 1 - first </td><td>Another New 1 - first </td></tr>
<tr><td>AnotherNew 1 - first </td><td>Another New 1 - first </td></tr>

</table>
EOT;
echo $html;
echo "<hr>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// returns all tables with class news
$tables = $xpath->query('//table[@class="news"]');
$requiredTable = ''; // This will html of tables
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $requiredTable .=  $doc->saveXML($table);
}
echo $requiredTable;
?>
```

This should print table in `$requiredTable` variable

Comment: Its so close. but I want the main tags. not plain text. any solution?

Comment: I have updated above code to return html of table

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strip_tags($text, "<table class='news'>|<tr>|<th>|<td>");
```

This should strip all tags except for those

```
echo strip_tags($text, "<table><tr><th><td>");
```

This would strip everything except for the string:

`<table><tr><th><td>`